# how to use loop in Jquery for input value display in another input?

Tags: jquery, loops

i have multi input fileds after clicking button , the all values of inputs display in another
input filed. input id from #blank1 to blank8

```js
$('#blank1').change(function () {
  let n1 = $(this).val();
  let text2 = $(this).val();
  text2 = $('#fillall').val();
  let sp = ' ';
  $('#fillall').val(text2+'{='+n1+sp+'}');
});
                   
$('#blank2').change(function () {
  let n1 = $(this).val();
  let text2 = $(this).val();
  let text3 = $(this).val();
  let text4 = $(this).val();
  let sp = ' ';
  text2 = $('#fillall').val().replace('}','');
  text3 = $('#fillall').val(text2+'='+n1+sp+'}').replace('}','');
  $('#fillall').val(text3);
});
```

Comment: Use a `for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++)` loop. You can use `'#blank' + i` to form a selector for each input.

Comment: But simpler would be to give all the inputs `class="blank"`. Then you can do `$(".blank").each()` to loop over them all.

Comment: Off topic: `text3 = $('#fillall').val(text2+'='+n1+sp+'}').replace('}','');` is wrong - not entirely sure what it should be, maybe `text3 = ($('#fillall').val()+text2+'='+n1+sp+'}').replace('}','');` - but `$(..).val(new_val)` returns the selector, not the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying really hard to understand your code snipet, but I can't.

So here is an answer to your question, while ignoring your code snippet:

```js
$(".copy").on("click", function() {
  let value = "";
  
  $(".copy-me").each(function() {
    value += $(this).val();
  });
  
  $(".output").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="copy-me">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="copy-me">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="copy-me">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="copy-me">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="copy-me">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="copy-me">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="copy-me">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="copy-me">
  <br>
</form>

Output: <input type="text" class="output">
  <br>
  <br>

<button class="copy">Copy all Inputs!</button>
```